# AngularJS, Select Box, Array of Objects, Need Name Shown but Value Sent to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am just learning angular JS, just coming out of the free codeschool course. I have searched and searched and searched for this, but came up empty. I've tried everything I can think of. Basically, I can't figure out what to put as the value of the ng-options directive.

I get an an array of objects from the database and am successfully getting it to the select box. The problem comes when trying to display it.

Here is a snippet of what I'm getting from the database:

```
[0 … 99]
0: Object
$$hashKey: "object:3"
school_id: "225"
school_name: "A L Hagen Jr High School"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
$$hashKey: "object:4"
school_id: "244"
school_name: "Academy for Children"
__proto__: Object
```

Here is my JS:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('addUser', []);
    app.controller('AddUserController', [ '$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope) {
        $scope.SchoolSelBox = null;
        $scope.schoolList = [];
        $http.post("lib/scripts/adding_user.php", {switch_id: '1', func: 'retrieve_schools'}).
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.schoolList = data;
                    console.log(data, status, headers, config)
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(data, status, headers, config);
                });
    }]);
})();
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<select ng-model="SchoolSelBox" ng-options="name for (value, name) in schoolList" id="school" class="adduser_input" style="width: 264px;"></select>
```

I need to display the name of the school in the select box, but the value I need to send back to the database for that user is the school ID and not the school name. I got it so it displays the school name, but I think what it is giving me to give to the database is the school name (which is not what I need).
So what in all worlds do I put inside ng-options?? Please?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: Oh, I know I have more than I need in my console.log's. I just wanted as much feedback as possible while I'm trying this out is all.

Comment: Try just `name for value in schoolList`.

Comment: That populates the select box with undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ng-options with this format.

**label for (key , value) in object**

Try this.

```
 <select ng-model="SchoolSelBox" ng-options="name.school_name for (key, name) in schoolList" id="school" class="adduser_input" style="width: 264px;"></select>
```

I created one example, http://plnkr.co/edit/OPN6MY?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Try using trackby (angular syntax for this is fairly awful)

```
<select ng-options="obj.school_name for obj in school_list track by obj.school_id" ng-model="selected" ></select>
```

Made an example at http://plnkr.co/edit/E0tWGOst9eZeVPJYHDRe
You can see the options have the value of the school_id and not the name